# Installing Waypoints and Animate.css

Tags: javascript, css, animate.css

How I can install the Waypoints javascript library and Animate.css an animation css library?

Comment: by install, do you mean include in a html page, or are you talking something like bower?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include external javascript files in you html, you use the `script` tag, like this:

`<script src="[the file path/url]"></script>`

to include a css file, you use the `link` tag

`<link href="[the file path/url]" rel="stylesheet" />`

Stylesheets should be loaded in the `head` tag, whilst `script` tags should be done at the end of the body (with some exceptioins such as pollyfils)

here is a [article on best practices](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/24-javascript-best-practices-for-beginners--net-5399) for loading your javascript files.

You can either load the files from a local copy (on your file system/server) or via a cdn, such as:

`<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.4.0/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.0/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>`

Don't forget, waypoints needs jquery, so load jquery **first**